# How to implement angularjs-permission in simple angular js login application ?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I wish to implement role based authentication in angular js login application. The project has been developed using node js with mongo db. I have to implement only client-side role-based authentication using angularjs-permission.

I have four controllers namely

1. Home Controller - Controls the view of the home page
2. Profil Controller - Displays the profile template
3. Login Controller - calls authentication service that handles user authorization
4. Navigation Controller - Displays the main template i.e. the actual html page in which other templates are inserted.

Comment: First thing is that you have to use routing for that, and then on route state change you can check for permission.

Comment: I have implemented routing. The application is running fine. so next step is to implement role based access to profile page. Need help with where to modify the code.

Comment: There's really no such thing as client side authentication, since anyone can forge anything on the client side.  The real authentication needs to happen on the back end.

Comment: I know this and am building this app to demonstrate the same.